# difficulty with -moz-animation

Tags: html, css

dear friends at the risk of being a pain can I humbly submit this code for your scrutiny for it appears to me that I have followed all the tutorials instructions only to come unstuck at the very end.  when I try to validate the code in CSS validation I get five warnings,

Sorry, the at-rule @-moz-keyframes is not implemented. 
Property -moz-animation is an unknown vendor extension

gulp!

For the life of me i cannot see where I have went wrong so if I could humbly ask for any assistance I will be most glad for it as its has been my ambition for some time to try to build a little slider, no matter how basic - kind regards MSK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#container{
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider{
border: 1px solid black;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#ffffff;
overflow:hidden;
 }

 div#slider ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
 }

 div#slider li{
position: absolute;
list-style:none;
 }

 div#slider ul li .animation_1{
-moz-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;
 }

 div#slider ul li .animation_2{
-moz-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
 }

 div#slider ul li .animation_3{
-moz-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
 }

 div#slider ul li .animation_4{
-moz-animation:cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
 }

 div#slider ul li .animation_5{
-moz-animation:cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
 }
@-moz-keyframes cycle{

        0%{top:0px;}
        4%{top:0px;}
        16%{top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0;}
        20%{top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0;}
        21%{top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1;}
        92%{top:-325px; opacity:0;}
        100%{top:0px; opacity:1;}
 }

 @-moz-keyframes cycletwo{

        0%{top:0px;}
        4%{top:0px;}
        16%{top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0;}
        20%{top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0;}
        21%{top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1;}
        92%{top:-325px; opacity:0;}
        100%{top:0px; opacity:1;}
 }

 @-moz-keyframes cyclethree{

        0%{top:0px;}
        4%{top:0px;}
        16%{top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0;}
        20%{top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0;}
        21%{top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1;}
        92%{top:-325px; opacity:0;}
        100%{top:0px; opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes cyclefour{

        0%{top:0px;}
        4%{top:0px;}
        16%{top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0;}
        20%{top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0;}
        21%{top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1;}
        92%{top:-325px; opacity:0;}
        100%{top:0px; opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes cyclefive{

        0%{top:0px;}
        4%{top:0px;}
        16%{top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0;}
        20%{top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0;}
        21%{top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1;}
        92%{top:-325px; opacity:0;}
        100%{top:0px; opacity:1;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li id="first" class="animation_1"><img src="bird.png"></li>
        <li id="second" class="animation_2"><img src="star.png"></li>
        <li id="third" class="animation_3"><img src="owl.png"></li>
        <li id="fourth" class="animation_4"><img src="shape.png"></li>
        <li id="fifth" class="animation_5"><img src="pony.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you still need the prefixe for animation in FF ?

Comment: probably not but once i get it working i can make it cross browser compatible - many thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

The animation classnames are on your li's, so you do not want a space between `li` and `.animation_X`:

```
div#slider ul li.animation_1 {
  -moz-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;
}
```

This worked fine for me otherwise in a local html file in firefox, though, the animations are the same, so you really only *see* one thing animating since they are all on top of each other. I assume you are still working on that.

Comment: thankyou very much the thing now works but when I validate it, the validation does not like my code!